# Get groupby sum of values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Documents looks like:

```
    {"_id":ObjectId("5c13fa0178cd81112f1d5ba5"),
    "availability":{"value":"Up","detail":[]}
    }
    {"_id":ObjectId("5c13fa0178cd81112f1d5ba6"),
    "availability":{"value":"Down","detail":[]}
    }
    {"_id":ObjectId("5c13fa0178cd81112f1d5ba7"),
    "availability":{"value":"Up","detail":[]}
    }
   {"_id":ObjectId("5c13fa0178cd81112f1d5ba8"),
    "availability":{"value":"Down","detail":[]}
    }
```

I am expecting the query output in the form:

```
{
"Up":2,
"Down":2
}
```

I tried:

```
my_coll.aggregate([
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$availability.value",
                    "availability": {"$sum": 1}
                }
            }

        ])
```

But its giving output as:

```
{'_id': 'Down', 'availability': 2}
{'_id': 'Up', 'availability': 2}
```

Can we achieve it through query or we have to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2nSIHJ1lhfH)

You have to use one more [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage and make a array with key value pair and finally use [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to convert it into
 single document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$availability.value",
    "availability": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id",
        "v": "$availability"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])
```